# Not sure how to setup these database tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

The weekends table will be created first so I am thinking an weekendsteam_id needs to be in weekends and do a select statement.  But I am getting really confused.  Basically the user will enter a weekend.  Then on a different view they will enter the team for that weekend.  I need to find a way to tie the two tables together so I can query it for the weekend view on the front end.

Weekends Table

```
    Schema::create('weekends', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->mediumText('verse');
            $table->string('songtitle');
            $table->string('songvideo');
            $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
            $table->string('videolink')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Weekends Team

```
    Schema::create('weekendteam', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('position');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use for a one-to-many relationship. Since it looks like you are storing the team members and their positions in the `weekendteam` table, you can simply add a `weekend_id` column (I also renamed the table to `weekend_team_members`):

```php
Schema::create('weekend_team_members', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('weekend_id');
    $table->string('firstname');
    $table->string('lastname');
    $table->string('position');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then, in order to get the team for any weekend, you can use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM weekend_team_members WHERE weekend_id = 1;
```

Which will fetch all of the team members for the weekend with that ID. If you are using Eloquent models, you can also use their built-in relationships to make querying easier:

```php
class Weekend extends Model {
...

    public function weekendTeamMembers() {
        return $this->hasMany(WeekendTeamMember::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class WeekendTeamMember extends Model {
...

    public function weekend() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Weekend::class);
    }
}
```

Once these relationships are defined in the models, you can use them to help you query the data. For example, if you already have a `Weekend` in the variable `$weekend`, you can fetch all of the team members like this:

```php
$teams = $weekend->weekendTeamMembers;
```

Or, if you have a team member, you can get the weekend like this:

```php
$weekendTeamMember->weekend;
```